# Using And where condition in Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What am trying to do is to use andWhere in my request

```
$passwordreset =  PasswordResets::where('token', $request->resetcode)
   ->andWhere('created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subHours(2))//error due to and
   ->first();
```

But the above returns an error.How can i perform this using the Model not DB:table since i would like a standard way of writing my code just by using the model.

Comment: what error? Can you show it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these methods in your Eloquent queries.

```
$passwordreset =  PasswordResets::where([
                      ['token', $request->resetcode],
                      ['created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(2)]
                  ])->first();
```

API Reference [`where()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where)